# Need a dialog box to browse computers on a network

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

The `FolderBrowserDialog` does allow me to browse computers on the network, but it displays other unnecessary folders (I don't want local folders).  Also, **I don't want to have to select a folder** - just the computer name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

The ComputerBrowserDialog

http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2008/04/how-to-browse-for-computer-name.html

I tweeked it a bit to behave more like the FolderBrowserDialog (only took a few min).  Works just how I want it to.

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var folderName = GetNetworkFolders(new FolderBrowserDialog());    
}

private string GetNetworkFolders(FolderBrowserDialog oFolderBrowserDialog)
{
    Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("rootFolder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(oFolderBrowserDialog, 18);
    if (oFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return oFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: this example does not include the requested functionality "_Also, I don't want to have to select a folder - just the computer name._"

Comment: Besides what Rlemon said, that code throws an error when casting 18 to a special folder type.  Says it doesn't exist (which it doesn't in .net 3.5 for some reason).

Comment: It does work with 4.0, weird that network folders type doesn't exist in 3.5

Answer (score 2):

ComputerBrowser.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class ComputerBrowser
{
    private FolderBrowserFolder _startLocation = FolderBrowserFolder.NetworkNeighborhood;
    private BrowseInfos _options = BrowseInfos.BrowseForComputer;
    private static readonly int MAX_PATH;
    private string _title;
    private string _displayName;
    private string _path;

    static ComputerBrowser()
    {
        MAX_PATH = 260;
    }

    public bool ShowDialog()
    {
        return ShowDialog(null);
    }

    public bool ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        _path = string.Empty;
        IntPtr handle;
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (owner != null)
            handle = owner.Handle;
        else
            handle = UnmanagedMethods.GetActiveWindow();
        UnmanagedMethods.SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(handle, (int)_startLocation, ref zero);
        if (zero == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;

        int num = (int)_options;
        if ((num & 0x40) != 0)
            Application.OleRequired();
        IntPtr pidl = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            BrowseInfo lpbi = new BrowseInfo();
            //IntPtr pszPath = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MAX_PATH);
            lpbi.pidlRoot = zero;
            lpbi.hwndOwner = handle;
            lpbi.displayName = new string('\0', MAX_PATH);
            lpbi.title = _title;
            lpbi.flags = num;
            lpbi.callback = null;
            lpbi.lparam = IntPtr.Zero;
            pidl = UnmanagedMethods.SHBrowseForFolder(ref lpbi);
            if (pidl == IntPtr.Zero)
                return false;
            _displayName = lpbi.displayName;

            StringBuilder pathReturned = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);

            UnmanagedMethods.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, pathReturned);
            _path = pathReturned.ToString();

            UnmanagedMethods.SHMemFree(pidl);

        }
        finally
        {
            UnmanagedMethods.SHMemFree(zero);
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected enum FolderBrowserFolder
    {
        Desktop = 0,
        Favorites = 6,
        MyComputer = 0x11,
        MyDocuments = 5,
        MyPictures = 0x27,
        NetAndDialUpConnections = 0x31,
        NetworkNeighborhood = 0x12,
        Printers = 4,
        Recent = 8,
        SendTo = 9,
        StartMenu = 11,
        Templates = 0x15
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum BrowseInfos
    {
        AllowUrls = 0x80,
        BrowseForComputer = 0x1000,
        BrowseForEverything = 0x4000,
        BrowseForPrinter = 0x2000,
        DontGoBelowDomain = 2,
        ShowTextBox = 0x10,
        NewDialogStyle = 0x40,
        RestrictToSubfolders = 8,
        RestrictToFilesystem = 1,
        ShowShares = 0x8000,
        StatusText = 4,
        UseNewUI = 80,
        Validate = 0x20
    }

    public static string GetComputerName(string title)
    {
        ComputerBrowser browser = new ComputerBrowser();
        browser._title = title;
        if (browser.ShowDialog())
            return browser._displayName;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Unmanaged.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ActivityMonitor.Monitor.Utils
{
    internal delegate int BrowseCallBackProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr lp, IntPtr wp);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct BrowseInfo
    {
        public IntPtr hwndOwner;
        public IntPtr pidlRoot;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string displayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string title;
        public int flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public BrowseCallBackProc callback;
        public IntPtr lparam;
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("00000002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMalloc
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        IntPtr Alloc(IntPtr cb);

        [PreserveSig]
        IntPtr Realloc(IntPtr pv, IntPtr cb);

        [PreserveSig]
        void Free(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig]
        IntPtr GetSize(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig]
        int DidAlloc(IntPtr pv);

        [PreserveSig]
        void HeapMinimize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A class that defines all the unmanaged methods used in the assembly
    /// </summary>
    internal class UnmanagedMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static System.IntPtr SHBrowseForFolder(ref BrowseInfo bi);

        [DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal extern static bool SHGetPathFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder pszPath);

        [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal extern static bool SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

        [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        internal extern static int SHGetMalloc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]out object shmalloc);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal extern static IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        public static extern int SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(IntPtr hwnd, int csidl, ref IntPtr ppidl);

        //Helper routine to free memory allocated using shells malloc object
        internal static void SHMemFree(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            object shmalloc = null;

            if (SHGetMalloc(out shmalloc) == 0)
            {
                IMalloc malloc = (IMalloc)shmalloc;

                (malloc).Free(ptr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From: [FolderBrowserDialog Unmasked: Everything You Wanted To Know About The Folder Browser Component From .Net Framework](http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm)

> No Filtering
>
> The FolderBrowserDialog has no support for filtering. For example, it
>   is not possible to display only network folders or only shared folders
>   or only folders starting with the string "Documents" or files having a
>   particular extension.

try using the openFileDialog and setup your filters.

Comment: The OpenFileDialog requires you to select a file.  I just want to select the computer/server name.